# Cyclomatic complexity error in my code

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint, cyclomatic-complexity

I am getting 2 errors in my grunt file

`line 61   col 25  This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (10)`

`line 101  col 22  This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (10)`

how could I reduce the Cyclomatic complexity in this case ? my functions aren't that complex

first error

```
    remove: function(line, row, type) {
      var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
        totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
        moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline'),
        lineValue;
      if (spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected) {
        switch (type) {
          case 'spread':
            lineValue = row.spread.line;
            break;
          case 'total':
            lineValue = row.total.line;
            break;
          case 'moneyline':
            lineValue = row.moneyLineId;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }

        AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(credentials) {
          betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/removeSelection', {
            customerId: credentials.customer,
            game: row.game,
            pair: row.pair,
            line: lineValue
          });
        });

        if (spreadSelected) {
          row.spreadSelected = false;
        }
        if (totalSelected) {
          row.totalSelected = false;
        }
        if (moneyLineSelected) {
          row.moneyLineSelected = false;
        }
      }
    }...
```

and then the 2nd error function

```
    add: function(line, row, type) {
      var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
        totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
        moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline'),
        lineValue;
      if (!(spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected)) {
        switch (type) {
          case 'spread':
            lineValue = row.spread.line;
            break;
          case 'total':
            lineValue = row.total.line;
            break;
          case 'moneyline':
            lineValue = row.moneyLineId;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(credentials) {
          betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/addSelection', {
            customerId: credentials.customer,
            game: row.game,
            pair: row.pair,
            line: lineValue
          });
        });
        switch (type) {
          case 'spread':
            row.spreadSelected = true;
            break;
          case 'total':
            row.totalSelected = true;
            break;
          case 'moneyline':
            row.moneyLineSelected = true;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

the weird thing here: this error is only with me, my co-worker opens the same files and run grunt and there is no errors in their terminals.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to reduce cyclomatic complexity of a function is to split it into several smaller functions and distribute that complexity into easy-to-understand chunks. For instance, you can extract your switch-case statement, resulting in something like this:

```
remove: function(line, row, type) {
    var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
        totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
        moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline'),
        lineValue;
    if (!(spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected)) {
        lineValue = getLineValue(row, type);
    }
    // ... and so on, in reasonable chunks.
}

function getLineValue(row, type) {
    var lineValue;
    switch (type) {
        case 'spread':
            lineValue = row.spread.line;
            break;
        case 'total':
            lineValue = row.total.line;
            break;
        case 'moneyline':
            lineValue = row.moneyLineId;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    return lineValue;
}
```

Then, we find that that you can reuse the `getLineValue` function in your second block as well:

```
add: function(line, row, type) {
    var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
        totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
        moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline'),
        lineValue;

    if (!(spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected)) {
        lineValue = getLineValue(row, type);
    }
    // ... and so on
}
```

So with this one change, you've distributed the complexity to another function, and also completely eliminated some complexity by eliminating duplication.